# Did Mary really attend the French class?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-caller

In The Caller, Mary attends a French class and she sits there with all the other children and is taught my a teacher (John).

> But later it is revealed that John died when he was a child and the body was never found. (It was found later behind the wall).

So does it mean that all of it is a hallucination?

> Just like she had with George the gardener?

If it is, what about the other children? And the whole class and the things that John mended in Mary's apartment (like the A/C)? Were they real or they too were hallucinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** it was not a hallucination.

The movie shows the call being happening through 2 different timelines. The caller speaking to the old Mary when she could see the little Mary growing up.

Since John threatens the caller when she was on phone, so she kills him by finding the little John and kills him and buries the body behind the wall. so doing that affects the entire reality happening around Mary except her, only she knows that the caller is doing this everyone else assumes that John went missing when he was a kid and never was found.

It happens the same way for every other instance caller does something to Mary.

Comment: Wow, never thought of it that way... Now it all makes sense- if you could call it that :). Thanks a lot +1